# jQuery - Text Description Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a grid of divs that show some of my work (portfolio), and I'm working on a mouse hover event that makes a title div move up and show a description.

Take a look:

http://olliejones.com/demo/demo.html

Now, as you can see, when you hover over a box, the title box moves up in height, showing a description. Works well I guess, but the description text (when you haven't hovered) is sitting under the div.

If you don't get what I mean, refresh the page, and Highlight everything (Cntl A)... You see the description text? Yeahh, how do I prevent that from happening? To only show when its hover is active, and don't show when hover isn't?

Here is my code, **HTML**, this is just the first row of divs (so the first 2 boxes):

```
        <div id="cube_base">    
            <div id="cube1" onmouseover="portfolio_hover_over(1);">
              <div id="cube_title1">Title
                <div id="cube_logo">
                    <img src="images/icons/photoshop.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" title='Adobe Photoshop'>
                    </div><br/><br/>
                <span class="cube_sub_title">This is a really long description about nothing. Here I begin to talk about nothing, rather interesting isn't it? Text goes here, and is seems like my imagination stops here.</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="cube_div"></div>

        <div id="cube_base">    
            <div id="cube2" onmouseover="portfolio_hover_over(2);">
                <div id="cube_title2">Title
                    <div id="cube_logo">
                        <img src="images/icons/photoshop.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" title='Adobe Photoshop'>
                    </div><br/><br/>
                <span class="cube_sub_title">This is a really long description about nothing. Here I begin to talk about nothing, rather interesting isn't it? Text goes here, and is seems like my imagination stops here.</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <br/>
        <div id="cube_gap"></div>
        <br/>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cube_div{
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:100px;
}
#cube_gap{
    width:800px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
}
.cube_sub_title{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: normal;    
}

#cube_title1{
    position:absolute;
    width:335px;
    height:15px;
    background-image: url(images/alpha_black_strong.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom:0px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#EEE;
}
#cube_title2{
    position:absolute;
    width:335px;
    height:15px;
    background-image: url(images/alpha_black_strong.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom:0px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#EEE;
}
#cube_base{
    width:355px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#080;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;

    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    background-image: url(images/icon_slate.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Logo placements */
#cube_logo{
    height:20px;
    float:right;
    left: 50px;
    margin-top:-2px;
}

/* Actual Content for the cube divs */
#cube1{
    position:relative;
    width:355px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #777;
}
#cube2{
    position:relative;
    width:355px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #777;
}
```

And My **JS**:

```
function portfolio_hover_over(cube){

    // hides the text panel
    for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if(i != cube){

            //animated panel back to 15px
            $('#cube_title'+i).animate({
                height: '15px'}, 200, function(){
            });
        }
    }


    $('#cube_title'+cube).animate({
        height: '130px'}, 200, function(){
    });


}
```

I know theres a lot here, but I would appreciate any help I could get on this, thanks!

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net to prepare the question so that we don't have to make the copy-paste ourselves, please.

Comment: Tim Banks's solution would do the trick, FYI : ID must be Unique to a single element on a page. Use classes instead.

Comment: Noted, and Thanks. Also, could someone tell me why their is a lag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `overflow:hidden` to the `#cube_base` css block